# Why are there are no prime divisors of $z^{4}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am not sure how the following statement makes sense. I understand that any common prime divisor of $x$ and $x^{2}+z^{4}$ would divide $z^{4} $because if $p|x $ => $p|x^{2}$ and $ p|(x^{2}+z^{4}-x^{2}) $ => $p|z^{4}$. But I don't understand why this means there are no common prime divisors?

Any help would be  much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Are you working in a polynomial ring with variables $x,z$?  over a field?

Comment: The only additional information I have is: Suppose x,y,z are non-zero integers with $y^{2} = x^{3}+xz^{4}$, and moreover suppose that x,z are coprime.

Comment: I am trying to show that x and x^2+z^4 are coprime.

Comment: "*And moreover suppose that $x,z$ are coprime*"  Now with your previous comment we learn you are not talking about working in a polynomial ring at least.  This particular passage is important.

Comment: Let $p$ be a common prime divisor of $x$ and $x^2+z^4$.  Then $p\mid x\implies p\mid x^2$ and since $p\mid x^2+z^4$ as well implies that $p\mid (x^2+z^4-x^2)$ i.e. $p\mid z^4$.  Now... since $p\mid z^4$ this implies that $p\mid z$...  That is to say, $p$ is a common divisor of $x$ and $z$, but we said that $x$ and $z$ are coprime